# putting offset of functions in array, and then calling function one by one

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Here is my question

Q)Write a function “addtoset” that takes offset of a function and
remembers this offset in an array that can hold a maximum of 8
offsets. It does nothing if there are already eight offsets in the set.
Write another function “callset” that makes a call to all functions in
the set one by one.

I am trying to do it with three functions initially, you can see in my code
(I am using NASM 16bit architecture)

Here is my code, it assembles but doesn't show any output, how can i fix it?

```
org 100h
segment data
arr dw 0,0,0
count dw 0
section .text
        mov bx , arr; assigning address of arr to bx

        mov ax , fun1;moving offset of fun1 to ax
        call addtoast

        mov ax , fun2;moving offset of fun2 to ax
        call addtoast

        mov ax , fun3;moving offset of fun3 to ax
        call addtoast

        call callset

end:
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H

callset:;this function will call other functions
        call arr
        call [arr+2]
        call [arr+4]
ret

addtoast:;this function puts offset into array
        mov [bx+count], ax
        add [count], word 2
ret

fun1:;prints 1
        mov dx , '1'
        mov ah , 2h
        int 21h
ret

fun2:;prints 2
        mov dx , '2'
        mov ah , 2h
        int 21h
ret

fun3:;prints 3
        mov dx , '3'
        mov ah , 2h
        int 21h
ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`call arr` doesn't do what you want, it goes to label `arr` instead of using it as a pointer. You need the brackets: `call [arr]`

`mov [bx+count],ax` doesn't do what you want either. It stores `ax` into memory `bx` bytes after the `count` label, instead of using it as a variable. Unfortunately x86 can't do this in one step, so you'll have to write something like:

```
mov si, [count]
mov [bx+si], ax
```

From a quick glance there are no other problems, but learn to use a debugger to step through the code if it still doesn't work.